# PHP sorting/oredring one dimensional array keys or any sorting orders

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

Consider following list:

```
$list = array(
        0 => A, 
        1 => X, 
        2 => B, 
        3 => Z, 
        4 => K, 
        5 => M
        );
```

I want to change position of A from 0 to 2 then the $list became:

```
$list = array(
        0 => X, 
        1 => B, 
        2 => A, 
        3 => Z, 
        4 => K, 
        5 => M
        );
```

#### The following code is what I have tried so far, is there another way using array functions? or any shorter way?

```
<?php
  $list = array(0 => 'A', 1 => 'X', 2 => 'B', 3 => 'Z', 4 => 'K', 5 => 'M');
  function change_position($oldposition, $newposition, $list){
    echo "Changing $oldposition to $newposition :\n";
    foreach($list as $k => $v){
         if($oldposition < $newposition){
            if( $k < $oldposition ){
              $newlist[$k] = $list[$k];
            }
            if($k >= $oldposition && $k < $newposition){
              $newlist[$k] = $list[$k+1];
            }
            if($k == $newposition){
             $newlist[$k] = $list[$oldposition];
            }
            if($k > $newposition){
             $newlist[$k] = $list[$k];
            }
         }
         if($oldposition > $newposition){
            if( $k > $oldposition ){
              $newlist[$k] = $list[$k];
            }
            if($k <= $oldposition && $k > $newposition){
              $newlist[$k] = $list[$k-1];
            }
            if($k == $newposition){
             $newlist[$k] = $list[$oldposition];
            }
            if($k < $newposition){
             $newlist[$k] = $list[$k];
            }
         }
   }
   return $newlist;
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($list);
print_r(change_position(5, 0, $list));
print_r(change_position(0, 5, $list));
?>
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => X
    [2] => B
    [3] => Z
    [4] => K
    [5] => M
)
Changing 5 to 0 :
Array
(
    [0] => M
    [1] => A
    [2] => X
    [3] => B
    [4] => Z
    [5] => K
)
Changing 0 to 5 :
Array
(
    [0] => X
    [1] => B
    [2] => Z
    [3] => K
    [4] => M
    [5] => A
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use [`array_splice`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php):

```
function move_element(&$array, $element, $position)
{
    $key = array_search($element, $array, true);
    if ($key === false) {
        return;
    }

    array_splice($array, array_search($key, array_keys($array)), 1);
    array_splice($array, $position, 0, $element);
}
```

Your example would be achieved with

```
move_element($list, 'A', 2);
```

If you don't want to specify the target as a value but as a position it's even easier:

```
function move_element(&$array, $from, $to)
{
    $removed = array_splice($array, $from, 1);
    array_splice($array, $to, 0, $removed);
}

move_element($list, 0, 2);
```

Comment: Thanks Jon, I tried, the problem here if you move any element it require re-ordering all elements...

Comment: @Akam splice it and then append it

Comment: @Jon: Thanks Anyway, however, I am not looking for this, altering two elements with each other is easy.

Comment: @Akam: Sorry, misread the question on the second try. Should be on point now.

Comment: yes, it's now what I am looking for [DEMO](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/daq-m94)